# Uploading multiple files from mutiple input fields in Nodejs using Multer

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, multer

I'm trying to upload files from the client side in Nodejs using multer middleware through this form:

html form:

```
<form action="/newStaff" method="post" class="form-group " enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p>
            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fName" name="firstName" placeholder="Applicant's First Name" >
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="oName">Other Name(s)</label>
                <input type="text" id="oName" name="otherName" placeholder="Applicant's Other Name(s)">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lName" name="lastName" placeholder="Applicant's last Name" >
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Female" > Female
                <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male" > Male
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="date of birth"> 
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="address">Home Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="homeAddress" placeholder="home address">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="contact">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="contact numbers">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="qualification">Highest Qualification:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="qualification" name="qualification">
                 
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="upCert">Certificates</label>
                <input type="file" id="upCert" name="certificate"   multiple>
            </p>
          
            <p>
                <label for="cv">Curriculum Vitae (CV)</label>
                <input type="file" id="cv" name="cv">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="photo">Photo</label>
                <input type="file" id="photo" name="p"  >
            </p>
            <p>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>
```

the middleware is:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
const multiUpload = upload.fields([{certificate: 'certificate', 5}, {cv: 'cv', 1}, {photo: 'photo', 1}]);
```

The post route is:

```
routes.post('/newStaff',multiUpload, cont.postNewStaffPage);
```

Note: I have my post handler file in the routes folder and not on the app.js.

So far I have been getting the same error message:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderPar    at SBMH.push (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Developer Folders\Nodejs\Nodejs Practices\Practice-2 EJS\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)
```

None of the input fields are sent presently, even the none file type inputs are not working.

I want all the files to upload